is there any better way to keep UV mirrored when I do symmetrical modeling using mirror modifier?
I have one polygon mesh which I always do something to like modeling, UV  mapping, texturing, weight painting, rigging at the same time. I ignore typical workflow when I mess with this mesh. I know I shouldn't touch UV map after finishing texturing, I shouldn't touch bone weight after animation but this base mesh needs something like it.
So I would like to optimize UV mapping workflow, so I made my base mesh completely symmetrical using mirror modifier. it's nice because this modifier lets me have not only symmetrical mesh structure and vertex group but symmetrical UV map too. So I don't need to think about UV mapping again and again when I do something in edit mode. I know if I edit mesh, UV will be broken too but I can edit mesh with texture, which is nice because I use texture as reference. To make it better I will make my texture structure symmetrical. Mirror modifier has an option "Mirror U" so if texture is drawn based on this option mesh with mirror modifier can have asymmetrical texture, but texture needs optimizing too because if I use "Mirror U", typical square ratio texture has lots of dead space in its width area so I will make 2k 2048x2048 texture into width 1024 height 4096 texture. file size is same but it's more efficient because its width area is smaller but height area has more space. I know UV map will be a problem when it's displayed on non-square texture, it will be distorted too but I just need to scale them. Not so hard to maintain.
What do you think? Is there any better way to deal with UV mapping when I do symmetrical modeling? Give me your thought please.
